# ActionBar tabs like in the yahoo mail app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm a beginner in Android. My question is how to create ActionBar tabs like yahoo mail?

Take a look at the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip you can put the tabs over the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>


    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:pstsActivateTextColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsDeactivateTextColor="#66323232"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/primary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsTabSwitch="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"/>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I have xml error for using  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. I import android-support-v7-appcompat in my project